# Select the children of $(this) that has the class name equal to X

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="my_div">
 <a class="x"></a>
<a class="y"></a>
<a class="z"></a>
..
</div>
```

I am trying to select a specific anchor by its class name. I tried:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myFunction = function(){
        $('div.my_div').on("mouseover", function(e){
            $(this).children().hasClass('x').css('background-color', 'blue');     
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Your usual guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't add "answered" to the question title.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, ok thank you for making me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.find(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/find/#find-selector) or [`.children(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/children/#children-selector)

> A string containing a selector expression to match elements against.

*Use*

```
 $(this).find('.x')
 //$(this).children('.x')
```

Comment: That's it, thank you for your quick feedback waiting for timer to expire. +1

Comment: I don't know why my mind didn't remember the first one even I already used it. Thanks for the second I didn't know `children()` accepts arguemnts

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces, Sometime that happens to even best of us